# Visual Basic Application.GetSaveAsFilename dialogue response

Tags: vba, modal-dialog, return-code

This must be the daftest question. I have the following VB code that pop's up a dialogue to save a PDF file when a button is hit.

It works fine, only I just realised that it executes the SAVE FILE even when the cancel button is being hit, which is bizarre unless of course I must handle the cancel event myself?

How would I go about that? what return codes do I have to check?

```
Sub SavePDF()

Dim PDFName As String

PDFName = ThisWorkbook.Name

PDFName = Left(PDFName, Len(PDFName) - 5)

PDFName = PDFName & ".pdf"

FullFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(PDFName, _
"PDF(*.pdf),*.pdf*", 1, "Save As PDF File")

'check return code only executing the following when the Save Button is proessed
'HOW DO I DO THIS?
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
PDFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
False

End Sub
```

Edit the day after post:
Still no answer to this - surely you can test the buttons in VB????!!

Answer (score 0):

```
If FullFileName = False
    Exit Sub
End If
```

This should work ...

Comment: That only works if the file name was **not** filled in. By default I'm getting the workbook name and then populating the popup dialogue with the that name, so if the user hits cancel the FullFileName will always be True. I would prefer a logic that tested the button that has been selected.